# uibutton add target selector method is called in calling class rather than in called class

Tags: ios, objective-c, view, uibutton, subview

viewcontroller1.m:

```
[view2 buttonClickCheck:cell];
```

selectormethod1:

```
-(void)mybuttonClick:(id)sender{
    NSLog(@"mybuttonClick");
}
```

view2.m

```
- (UITableViewCell*) buttonClickCheck: (UITableViewCell*) cell{
        NSLog(@"button click check");

        UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(cell.frame.origin.x,
                                                                cell.frame.origin.y,
                                                                self.parentViewController.view.frame.size.width,
                                                                frameSize)];
        view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];


        UIButton *mybutton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(view.frame.origin.x,view.frame.origin.y, frameSize, frameSize)];
        mybutton.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
        [mybutton addTarget:self action:@selector(mybuttonClick:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

        [view addSubview:mybutton];
        [cell addSubview:view];

        return cell;

    }

    -(void)mybuttonClick:(id)sender{
        NSLog(@"mybuttonClick");
    }
```

The problem is on clicking the button, mybuttonClick method of viewcontroller1 is called instead of viewcontroller2, I check self object in viewcontroller 2 it refers to viewcontroller2 itself.

if I comment mybuttonclick in viewcontroller1, nothing gets printed on clicking the button.

note: viewcontroller2 is just a class, inheriting nsobject, it is not connected to any story board, but viewcontroller1 is

Comment: did you connect it right in storyboard/interface builder?

Comment: @dan viewcontroller2 is just a class inheriting nsobject

Comment: so you connected the button to viewController1`s myButtonClick?

Comment: @dan you see, myButtonClick is a selector method, and I have dynamically specified the targed. there is no static button in story board, I have dynamically created it

Comment: Ok, another shot in the dark: Did you add a target to the button? `button addTarget:self 
           action:@selector(aMethod:)
 forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];` and all that?

Comment: I just checked, uibutton does not have any delegate instance, besides why a delegate

Comment: refresh the page, I updated the comment, sorry.

Comment: @dan: oh dan, you can see addTarged method in my view2.m code right

Comment: yes, but target is `self`, which is `viewController2`. I that the problem maybe?

Comment: @dan: yes self is viewcontroller2, but mybuttonclick is being called from viewcontroller1, I want it to call from viewcontroller2. I dont seem to understand why is that happening

Comment: when target is `viewController2`, the `mybuttonclick` from `viewController2` will be called. Try to set an instance of `viewController1` as the target.

Comment: @dan: hey, I want mybuttonclick to be called from viewcontroller2 which is not happening.

Comment: sorry I was confused ^^

Answer (score 0):

If `ViewController2` is type of `NSObject` class, then check you have implement like following

in `ViewController1.m` file

```
ViewController2 *view2 = [[ViewController2 alloc] init];
[view2 buttonClickCheck:cell];
```

And check that in `ViewController2.h`, you must have declare method,

```
- (UITableViewCell*) buttonClickCheck: (UITableViewCell*) cell;
```

Then your method definitely make call.

And it is better to give name of class according to its type. Like is your class is type of `NSObject` Then its name should be like `View2` instead of `ViewController2` so you don't get confused. (It is for your conveniency)

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because you pass cell from viewcontroller1.m to view2.m here: `[view2 buttonClickCheck:cell];`, Than in `(UITableViewCell*) buttonClickCheck: (UITableViewCell*) cell` you create `UIView *view`, add it to your cell as subview, and add your button to your *view

Comment: that's exactly what I am doing, what do you suggest that I do that my mybuttonclick gets called from viewcontroller2

Comment: if you can access view2 like this viewcontroller1.view2 try to use instead of `[mybutton addTarget:self action:@selector(mybuttonClick:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];`  `[mybutton addTarget:self.view2 action:@selector(mybuttonClick:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];`